# Can I shrink and then rotate an ImageButton upon click in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an ImageButton that I would like to animate in such a way that it appears depressed (just shrinking the image slightly) and then spins once when clicked before returning to its normal size.

**Is there a standard way of accomplishing something like this?**

The ImageButton XML is:

```xml
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/rollButton"
        android:layout_width="168dp"
        android:layout_height="124dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.000"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/dice" />
```

The button click already accomplishes its primary goal by calling a function in `MainActivity.kt`:

```kotlin
val rollButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.rollButton)
        rollButton.setOnClickListener {
            resultsTextView.text = ThingThatDoesStuff().doSomeStuff()
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read the documentation for [Animations and Transitions](https://developer.android.com/training/animation), or follow this [Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2785491-android-animation-tutorial-with-kotlin) by Kevin Moore if you want a more hands-on approach.

For your specific problem you can use this solution,

MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val rollButton: ImageButton = findViewById(R.id.rollButton)

        rollButton.setOnClickListener {
            it.roll()
        }
    }
}

fun View.roll(shrinkFactor: Float = 0.8f, duration: Long = 500) {
    val downscaleAnimator = AnimatorSet()
    downscaleAnimator.playTogether(
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "scaleX", 1f, shrinkFactor),
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "scaleY", 1f, shrinkFactor))

    val rotationAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "rotation", 360f)

    val upscaleAnimator = AnimatorSet()
    upscaleAnimator.playTogether(
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "scaleX", shrinkFactor, 1f),
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "scaleY", shrinkFactor, 1f))

    val combinedAnimator = AnimatorSet()
    combinedAnimator.playSequentially(downscaleAnimator, rotationAnimator, upscaleAnimator)
    combinedAnimator.duration = duration
    combinedAnimator.doOnEnd { this.rotation = 0f }
    combinedAnimator.start()
}
```

Comment: This worked great. I had to replace `combinedAnimator.addListener...` with `combinedAnimator.doOnEnd { this.rotation = 0f }`. Thanks for the documentation and tutorial links as well!

Comment: @muad-dweeb You're welcome! I've updated my answer to use the syntax you suggested, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about shrink but you can rotate by using these lines:

```
private void rotateView(TextView view){
    Integer rotationAngle = 90; rotation angle
    RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(-rotationAngle, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f); //seting animation 
    view.setRotation(rotationAngle);
    rotate.setDuration(500); //animation duration
    rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    view.startAnimation(rotate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
     imageButton = findViewById(R.id.imageButton)

        imageButton.setOnClickListener {

            it.animate().scaleXBy(-0.2f).scaleYBy(-0.2f)
                .rotation(5f).duration = 500
                it.isEnabled = false
        }
```

You can change The values for better purpose .

Comment: This solution shrunk and slightly tilted the button.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and dirty version

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    findViewById<Button>(R.id.button).setOnClickListener {
        it.doAnimation()
    }
}

private fun View.doAnimation() {
    animate().scaleX(0.8f).scaleY(0.8f).withEndAction {
        animate().rotationBy(360f).withEndAction {
            animate().scaleX(1f).scaleY(1f).start()
        }.start()
    }.start()
}
```

where you're just chaining runnables with [`ViewPropertyAnimator`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation#views)
calls - each `animate()` call creates one, but it's an "animate all the things together" deal, so you can do your scaling at the same time, but if you want something to follow it, you need to do that animation as a separate action.

This might be ok for simple things, but it might start to look a bit complex. If you want to choreograph things more clearly, you might want to look at [`AnimatorSet`s](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation#choreography), which require the older `ObjectAnimator` style:

```
private fun View.doAnimation() {
    val shrinkX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "scaleX", 0.8f)
    val shrinkY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "scaleY", 0.8f)
    val spin = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "rotation", 360f)
    val growX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "scaleX", 1f)
    val growY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "scaleY", 1f)

    AnimatorSet().apply {
        play(shrinkX).with(shrinkY)
        play(spin).after(shrinkX)
        play(growX).after(spin)
        play(growY).with(growX)
    }.start()
}
```

it's more verbose but hopefully it's pretty easy to follow! And if you do things this way, you can [make the equivalent as an XML resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource#Property) and use the animation wherever

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- res/animator/sproing.xml -->
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:ordering="sequentially">
    <set>
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="200"
            android:propertyName="scaleX"
            android:valueTo="0.8" />
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="200"
            android:propertyName="scaleY"
            android:valueTo="0.8" />
    </set>

    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/anticipate_interpolator"
        android:duration="500"
        android:propertyName="rotation"
        android:valueTo="360f" />

    <set>
        <objectAnimator
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator"
            android:duration="400"
            android:propertyName="scaleX"
            android:valueTo="1" />
        <objectAnimator
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/overshoot_interpolator"
            android:duration="400"
            android:propertyName="scaleY"
            android:valueTo="1" />
    </set>
</set>
```

and in the activity:

```
val anim = AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.animator.sproing)
findViewById<Button>(R.id.button).setOnClickListener { view ->
    anim.setTarget(view)
    anim.start()
}
```

once you have this set up it's pretty easy to tweak things, move stuff into the same set so it happens at the same time, throw delays on etc... plus you can use Apply Changes in the IDE and it updates pretty much immediately, so it's easy to play with timings. And I threw some interpolators on there because why the heck not